# Is it possible to add Instagram action to Activity Sheet using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, instagram, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am creating an iOS app which enables users to post an image to one of three (or all three) social media providers including: Twitter, Facebook and Instagram.

I have tried implementing this functionality using the UIDocumentInteractionController(), whilst this was effective in adding the 'Copy to Instagram' icon option, it didn't allow me to add icons/options for Facebook and Twitter sharing.

After spending an hour or so Googling solutions to my problem, I came across UIActivityViewController which looked promising. I have implemented an activity sheet which allows me to share via Facebook and Twitter which is brilliant, however, does anybody know how I go about integrating the 'copy in instagram' option to the sheet?

```
    @IBAction func shareInstagramPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(newImageData.length != 0){
            let image = UIImage(data:newImageData, scale:1.0)
            displayShareSheet(image!)
        }
        else {
            print("Please select an image first")
        }
    }

    func displayShareSheet(shareContent:UIImage) {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareContent as UIImage], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
            UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
            UIActivityTypePrint,
            UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
            UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
            UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
            UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
            UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks,
            UIActivityTypeMessage,
            UIActivityTypeMail
        ]
        presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
    }
```

Comment: How did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes:**

...it is *technically* possible, but this support *should* probably come from Instagram.

From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html):

> You should subclass UIActivity only if you want to provide custom services to the user. The system already provides support for many standard services and makes them available through the UIActivityViewController object. For example, the standard activity view controller supports emailing data, posting items to one of the user’s social media accounts, and several other options. You do not have to provide custom services for any of the built-in types.

**No:**

Instagram has no current support for `UIActivity`.

From the [Instagram Documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/):

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```